# Android phone won't boot up after rooting

Tags: rooting, recovery-mode, broken-screen, unrooting, micromax-unite

I did rooting for the first time on my device
**MICROMAX UNITE 3**
**model: Q372**
I installed SuperSU and granted the permission to it to become superuser and thing is I haven't done any data recovery using CWM or TWRP .Next thing I did is rebooted my phone and I got this black screen of death .
So what did I do is pressed the **volume up+ power button** to go into recovery mode and it shows that **no command** with a dead logo. Then I pressed **powerbutton + menu button(down)**  and got this

[image]

I wiped cached partition ,nothing happened still black screen.
there is no recovery of TWRP / CWM .
no update from adb.

I am stuck with black screen , what should I do?

Comment: Which SuperSU did you flash and what is your Android version?

Comment: android v5.0 and the SuperSU me @beeshyams

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with that method to suggest

Comment: @beeshyams It's all solved. The thing is that some permissions were overwritten .I  just have  to flash a new stock ROM with SP flash tool and that's all the bootloop was gone and the permissions were restored.

Comment: You can write that up in details as an answer. It's encouraged to provide your own solutions